# SP2013, full crawl error: The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. ( Index was out of range. Must be non

Tags: crawl, index

I am using sp2013 standard. I first reset the index. And after this I did a full crawl. In the crawl history I see many errors like this below. What is going wrong?

```
sps3://amijnprofiel.myCompany.com/site$$$people/bucketid=1/itemid=987 

The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. ( Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index; ; SearchID = 98892BCF-E9F0-446B-89B6-A3B9A7DDC65D )
```

Update:
I also see that there are many people not crawled. I have a people searche result webpart. When I search on some users I cannot find them. This morning they were findable. I reset the index. After this reset some users are not findable.

Comment: did you try to stop & start the search services? usaully this ends up to recreate the Search Services App.

Comment: Is a reboot also ok?

Comment: try that one, but looks like corruption happen

Comment: I restarted the frontend/app server. It didnt help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SharePoint internal errors may not always say exactly what is wrong. Instead, they throw a general error at you and you’re on your own with your favorite search engine. This could very well be the cause in your case, which may be difficult to find.

There are however, cases where your error is caused by the use of multiple values flag on a site column doesn’t match the multiple values flag of the managed property. As an example, you may not permit multiple values on a site column, but your managed property does. This gives your error message according to Kanithi’s post [“SharePoint search – The content processing pipeline failed to process the item”](http://kanithi.wordpress.com/2014/08/26/sharepoint-search-the-content-processing-pipeline-failed-to-process-the-item/)

Find an erroneous item in the crawl log and see if this is the case in your environment.

## Site Column property

[image]

## Managed Property in Search Service Application

[image]

Comment: But what to do for managed properties which are not site columns? Like PhoneNumber, this is userprofile property.

Comment: Thanks Benny, I turned off the multiple option in the PhoneNumber managed property. Did a full crawl and now it is working fine. I can find all users in the people search.

Comment: @Ola I'm having a similar issue and people search returns empty results. I turned off multiple value option but still issue persists. any idea?

Comment: Thanks Benny, very helped :)