# Managed Metadata allow mulitple values cannot be crawled

Tags: crawling, crawled-property

I am using SP2013 on-premise. On a site collection's Pages library there is a Managed metadata column "Wiki Category" and allowed mulitple values. At the same time I have enabled multiple values for a managed property "ows_taxId_Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories".

However, the crawl log for most pages return error:

> The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. ( Index
>   was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection. Parameter name: index; ; SearchID =
>   E2DFE16B-1234-4F1A-4567-02552018E642 )

According to 
[SP2013, full crawl error: The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. ( Index was out of range. Must be non](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113524/sp2013-full-crawl-error-the-content-processing-pipeline-failed-to-process-the) I think I did it correctly. What else could lead to the error? I have tried remove the Managed metadata column and the search is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the ULS log with the Search ID. You might find more information in the Logs.
I faced a similar issue, and after checking the ULS logs, I found that 'ExcludeFromSummary' is mis-configured.

Check this article if it helps - http://spdeveloper.co.in/sharepoint2013/search-crawl-content-processing-pipeline-failed.aspx

Comment: Ram, I have read your article before. I have tried uncheck the "allowed mulitple values" for both the MP and the site column. The search will go smooth. However I need the column to allow mulitple values. What can I do?