# People results - The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. ( Index was out of range

Tags: search, search-results, people-search, managed-property

We have a SharePoint 2013 (enterprise) SharePoint farm. I had issues resetting the index and it timed out and I followed this article http://www.thetugboatcomplex.com/?p=1102 and was able to successfully reset the index. After resetting the index I started a full crawl and noticed that search was unable to crawl mysite and searching for people returned empty results. The following was the error. I was able to figure out the issue based on this two articles. [SP2013, full crawl error: The content processing pipeline failed to process the item. ( Index was out of range. Must be non](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113524/sp2013-full-crawl-error-the-content-processing-pipeline-failed-to-process-the) and http://www.ericjochens.com/2015/11/sharepoint-search-content-processing.html

[image]

There was an issue with "LastName" managed property in search schema which has "Allow Multiple Values" enabled. I unchecked this property and did a full crawl but I still get the error as shown above.

To further troubleshoot this issue I removed the "Last Name" values (in central admin -> user profile) of all the user profiles and did a full crawl again and noticed that errors went away and I was able to search people results. If I add the Last Name back in user profiles I get this error again.

Now my question is, how do I further troubleshoot this issue and figure out exactly how Last Name managed property is causing this issue?

Any Search 'Guru' out there?

Comment: Is recreating the Search Service Application an option? It sounds like that might be a solution at this point.

Comment: I have created few custom managed properties and built few functionalities based on these. Few have recommended that fixing the managed property might resolve this issue...

Comment: I would agree, but without a better look at the logs, it may be faster to start over. It's up to you.